# Trump's voting rights

Tags: criminal-law, florida, voting

If I recall correctly the State of Flordia restricts a person's right to vote if convicted of certain crimes. If Donald Trump is found guilty in any of his criminal cases could he potentially no longer be able to vote in the State of Flordia?